# Get the only one row from detail with matching header record in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a header table and a details with the following details

**Header**

```
ID      Name        Address 
-----------------------------
1000    Header 1    Address 1   
1010    Header 2    Address 2   
1020    Header 3    Address 3   
1030    Header 4    Address 4   
1040    Header 5    Address 5
```

**Details**

```
DetailID      HeaderID          DetailDesc  DetailType
------------------------------------------------------
1000-1          1000            Detail 1    Type 1
1000-2          1000            Detail 2    Type 2
1000-3          1000            Detail 3    Type 3
1010-1          1010            Detail 4    Type 1
1020-1          1020            Detail 5    Type 1
1020-2          1020            Detail 6    Type 2
1030-1          1030            Detail 7    Type 1
1030-2          1030            Detail 8    Type 2
```

I need to get a result ( top 1 of matching record in header)

```
ID      DetailID    Name        Address
------------------------------------------
1000    1000-1      Header 1    Address 1
1010    1010-1      Header 2    Address 2
1020    1020-1      Header 3    Address 3
1030    1030-1      Header 4    Address 4
```

I have need to get the records from both the tables matching ID  and only one record from detail.

Hope I explained the problem properly. Can you please help me to write a SQL query.

```
SELECT 
    H.ID, D.HeaderID, H.Name, H.Address 
FROM 
    Header AS H 
JOIN 
    Details AS D ON H.ID = D.HeaderID
```

Here I am getting all the details, I mean 8 records instead of 4

Comment: Based on your sample data it's as simple as adding `WHERE D.DetailType='Type1'`. In fact the only field you are getting from detail is just headerid with `-1` appended

Comment: can you explain bit more

Comment: you don't need to join to `Details` table as you are not selecting any column from it. Looks like what you need is just a list of `Header` with rows in `Details`. You can use `EXISTS()` to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT H.ID, D.DetailsID, H.name, H.Address
FROM Header H
LEFT OUTER JOIN Details D  
    ON H.ID = D.HeaderID 
WHERE D.DetailType = 'Type1';
```

This query will give desired result, as you mentioned in sample output.
Here we are using WHERE clause to filter records.

Comment: `left join...where` doesn't make sense, you end up filtering out all the non-matched row anyway. Either do `inner join ... where` or `left join... on` only